# Show that $\binom{n}{k}$ equals to $\binom{n-1}{k}\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{k}$.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

It should be solved by using combinatorial proofs.

Comment: What have you searched for?

Comment: May be he is asking for $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1}\cdot \frac{n-k+1}{k}$

Answer (score 3):

(As noted by juantheron, there is an error in the question title. It should be as it is in the body of this answer)

A classic method for combinatorial explanation of such equations usually uses counting the same thing in two different ways.
This case,$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1}\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{k}$$
is a simple example, as $\binom{n}{k} $ is the number of ways of choosing $k$ objects from a collection of $n$.

Another way to count the ways would be to first choose a collection of $k-1$ objects, leaving $n-(k-1)=n-k+1$. We can then take any of the $n-k+1$ remaining objects and add it to our collection, giving a collection of $k$ objects. But this method counts each such collection multiple times! Given any collection of $k$ objects, by first taking $k-1$ and then the remaining $1$, we see there are $k$ ways of getting the collection. Thus each such collection is counted $k$ times.

So we have a total of $$\binom{n}{k-1}\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{k}$$
$\binom{n}{k-1}$ for the ways to pick $k-1$ from $n$, multiplied by the $(n-k+1)$ ways to pick a $k^{th}$ element and the $1/k$ accounts for counting each possibility $k$ times.

So the number of ways to choose $k$ from $n$ is $\binom{n}{k-1}\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{k}$. But this is exactly $\binom{n}{k}$. Thus we arrive at the desired equality.